# Verbless Clause

Tags: grammaticality, clauses

Can anyone verify for me if this is a valid verbless clause? My editor is questioning the lack of a verb (this is for social media copy and would be followed by a URL) but I think it's valid.

> This session, along with every other event session, available to you on-demand:

I mean, personally, I think social media content should be a little less beholden to pure grammar rules and follow a pattern more akin to the spoken word. However my work editor tends to not be ... 100% accurate.

Comment: Verbs will make the sentence easier to read, and you avoid annoying some readers. "This session is available to you on demand (as is all other sessions):" is easier to parse.

Comment: Nope. Nope. Nope.   Only as "ad-speak".  *Available to you on demand—this session and every session!*    But your syntax is a little more complex than typical ad-speak admits.  The absence of **is** is jarring in your context.

Comment: Also, why are you ending the clause with a colon?

Comment: It's a fragment, not a sentence. In certain contexts, it would be a good fragment. But ELU cannot rule on what those contexts are. If your editor insists on true sentence structure, you have to decide on whether your style sense should come before your job. (And formal paper srutineers would not accept 'journalese'.)

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, the 'is' in this case is self interpreted for most readers. However, my suggestion is to restrict the use of such composition for taglines / punchlines - more often referred as 'Call to Action' in online marketing. 
This statement may only be considered inappropriate if used in a paragraph / description format as that's where we expect complete and accurate use of grammar.

Answer (score 0):

There's an implied 'is' in that sentence, without which it doesn't really have meaning.  To me, as a borderline autistic native English speaker who has spent a considerable amount of time learning to understand people over my life, that sentence seems perfectly understandable.  I doubt it would be so understandable to some of the members of the ELL SE.

That having been said, given the WWW, and a link immediately after that text pointing to a page with a table of links for those sessions, it's likely even they would be able to figure it out.